# Renaming files on my PC all at once without external program

Tags: windows, file

I want to rename several files at once. For example, change `_` to `-`. I don't want to install and external program and want to know if there is an inbuilt feature. I am running Windows 10.

Comment: What language do you plan to use to write this script? ( see stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A VBS Script File should work.

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder("File Location")

For Each File In Folder.Files
    sNewFile = File.Name
    sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile,"ReplaceThis","WithThis")
    if (sNewFile<>File.Name) then 
        File.Move(File.ParentFolder+"\"+sNewFile)
    end if

Next
```

Save it as `.vbs` and run it.

NOTE: This isn't the place to ask questions like this. [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com) would be ideal for these kind of questions.